# what is the minium requirement to verify keycloak token?

Tags: jwt, token, keycloak

A user logs into Keycloak. They generate an jwt access token. The user provides this token to a service secured with Keycloak.

What must the service verify in the token to ensure the token is valid?

The expiration date of the token and the issuer are two aspects of the token I am currently verifying. What else is required? What other token verification provides better security?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you verifying token manually and not letting keycloak adapters do it for you?

Comment: I tried to use the adapters. Believe me I have tried everything and can't get them to work. Were you able to get them to work? If yes, please show me how!

Comment: Yes, I have been able to use Jetty adapter for securing my rest apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually access tokens contain several claims. Verification of mere expiration time and issuer won't be enough to secure the service.

You have to validate the signature of the token through the identity provider. You can also check whether the audience claim (3rd party application which is accessing the service) is valid as well. You can always add custom claims to the token that are unique to your service so that you can verify them to determine whether the token is valid or not.

Furthermore, you can call the introspection endpoint of the identity provider with the access token to check whether the token is active or not (whether it has been already used).